# How to show the popup menu using left click in cxbutton (devexpress Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7

I have a popup menu attached to a cxbutton (devexpress component for Delphi), the right mouse click shows the menu but now i need it by the left mouse click.

Please i checked all properties of the cxbutton but no one seems to do so, how to do ?

I m using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
procedure TForm1.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopUpMenu1.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y);
end;
```

?  For me, this works in D7 and the PopUpMenu appears at the same position is if it were right-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the popup of `Dexpress` you can call:

```
procedure TForm1.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   dxBarPopupMenu1.PopupFromCursorPos
end;
```